# Microsoft analytics : pull data from microsoft my analytics

Tags: azure-web-app-service

It is possible to pull Microsoft my analytics data via rest service since it is sensitive in nature so I am a bit skeptical if it's possible. any leads?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to pull personal data due to privacy regulations, such as General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR). Please read this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/workplace-analytics/myanalytics/overview/privacy-guide) for more information.